# Android newbie - Debugging app with extenrnal dependencies on physical device

Tags: azure, android-studio, azure-communication-services

I'm brand new to Andoid Studio I built an app following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/how-tos/calling-sdk/manage-calls?pivots=platform-android#accept-a-call) which works well on the emulator, but when I try to run it on my physical device (connected via USB), the app gets deployed and starts but as soon as I click a button that includes calls to 'com.azure.android:azure-communication-calling:1.0.0'" the app crashes with the error -

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com/microsoft/media/NTLMEngineImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ASAuPXcIxSXpXvIXvdBz6Q==/com.example.intercom-trFe1JVZL8mL-E4KBKikCg==/base.apk"]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code in the androidmanifest.xml file under  tag.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

checkout the link for solution
https://github.com/Laerdal/Xamarin.AzureCommunicationCalling/issues/1